# How to open new console window to print output of second thread there?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, console

I am using c++ 11 on windows platform, and i wanted to know how to open a new console window to display output from a child thread.

```
mutex mu;
bool flag = false;
void printg()
{

    int j=printf("testing /");
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;true;)
    {
        sleep(1.0);
        printf("\b");
        printf("\\");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1.0);
        printf("\b");
        printf("/");
        fflush(stdout);
        count++;
        lock_guard<mutex> gaurd(mu);
        if(flag)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    thread t(printg);
    pid_t p ;

    sleep(5);
    mu.lock();
    flag = true;
    mu.unlock();
    t.join();
    cout<<endl<<"hello "<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want the output of thread t on a different window and/or console, separate from the parent thread. In the long run i want to detach the thread and make it powerful enough to display output on its own window. Is there a work around this. I am working on windows 7 machine.

Comment: Reading a [Windows console function reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be a good start.

Comment: Windows only allows one console per process, so you need a 2nd process and an IPC channel (e.g. namedpipes, sockets, shared memory).

Comment: so ieven if my thread becomes a deamon process ie parent finishes and child process is still running. can i then open a new console.